# Why is my constructor being filled with something it "shouldn't"

Tags: java

First off, I am sorry for the broad title, I was not exactly sure how to phrase it. Anyways I am making a bank program that allows multiple people to have multiple accounts. However whenever a new person makes an account, it adds that account to everyone else is why. I have tried everything I could think of and have had no luck. I am aware that the manage class is probably not needed but it was one of the things I tried to fix my issue with. Also, the final 2 classes are for checking and savings accounts which I will finish once I fix this issue.
Any help is appreaciated :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

class Bank implements Comparable {

private double bal;
private int accountNumber;
private String accountName;

public Bank() {
}

void display_details() {
    System.out.println("Account Number : " + accountNumber);
    System.out.println("Account Balance : " + bal + "\n\n\n");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Account Name:" + accountName + "\nAccount Number : " + accountNumber + "\nAccount Balance : " + bal,
            "You own " + FinancialFolk.Bank.size() + " account[s]", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
    bal += depositAmount;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your new balance is: $" + bal);
}

public void withdraw(double withdrawAmount) {
    if (withdrawAmount > bal) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient Funds");
    } else {
        bal -= withdrawAmount;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your new balance is: $" + bal);
    }
}

public void transfer() {

}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public double getBal() {
    return bal;
}

public void setBal(double baL) {
    bal = baL;
}

public int getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumbe) {
    accountNumber = accountNumbe;
}

public String getAccountName() {
    return accountName;
}

/**
 * @param accountName the accountName to set
 */
public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
    this.accountName = accountName;
}

}

class FinancialFolk implements PasswordVerifivation {
private String accountUsername, accountHolderName, accountPassword;
protected ArrayList<Bank> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
protected static ArrayList<FinancialFolk> Bank = new ArrayList<>();
private int memberTime;

public FinancialFolk(String username, String name, String password) {
    accountUsername = username;
    accountHolderName = name;
    accountPassword = password;
}

public FinancialFolk() {
    accountUsername = "";
    accountHolderName = "";
    accountPassword = "";
}

public void passwordCreation() {
    accountPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose a secure password for your account.");
}

public boolean passwordVerify(String attemptedPassword) {
    return accountPassword.equals(attemptedPassword);

}

public boolean createNewPerson() { // Creates a new FinancialFolk.
    accountHolderName = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name."));
    if (accountHolderName == null)
        return false;
    String Username = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a username for your account."));
    for (FinancialFolk fk : Bank) {
        if (fk.getAccountUsername().equals(Username)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That username is taken!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    accountUsername = Username;
    passwordCreation();
    return true;
}

public void createNewAccount() { // Adds an account to an existing FinancialFolk.
    Bank check = new Checking();
    Bank save = new Savings();
    String[] buttons = { "Checking", "Savings" };
    int acc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What type of account would you like to make?", "Bank",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 1, null, buttons, buttons[1]);
    switch (acc) {
    case 0:
        check.setAccountName((JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name for this account.")));
        check.setAccountNumber((int) (Math.random() * 3000 + 1091));
        accounts.add(check);
        check.display_details();
        break;
    case 1:
        save.setAccountName((JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name for this account.")));
        save.setAccountNumber((int) (Math.random() * 3310 + 789));
        accounts.add(save);
        save.display_details();
        break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bank user = new Bank();
    FinancialFolk FF = new FinancialFolk();
    boolean exit = false;
    do {
        String[] buttons = { "Create Account For The First Time", "Login", "Exit Bank", "" };
        int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What would you like to do?", "Bank", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                3, null, buttons, buttons[3]);
        switch (rc) {
        case 0: // create account
            if (FF.createNewPerson()) {
                Bank.add(FF);
                Bank.get(Bank.size() - 1).createNewAccount();
            }
            break;
        case 1: // login
            boolean logout = false;
            boolean incun = true;

            String an = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your username.\n");
            String ps = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your acccount password.\n");
            for (FinancialFolk x : Bank) {
                if (x.getAccountUsername().equals(an)) {
                    incun = false;
                    if (x.passwordVerify(ps)) {
                        do {
                            String[] buttons2 = { "View all accounts.", "Deposit into an account",
                                    "Withdraw from your account", "Change password", "Create another bank account",
                                    "Logout" };
                            int rc2 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What would you like to do?", "Bank",
                                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 3, null, buttons2, buttons2[4]);
                            switch (rc2) {
                            case 0: // all accounts
                                int networth = 0;
                                for (Bank acct : FF.accounts) {
                                    acct.display_details();
                                    networth += acct.getBal();
                                }
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                        "Your account total between all accounts: $" + networth);
                                break;
                            case 1: { // deposit
                                if (x.accounts.size() == 0)
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have any accounts!");
                                else if (x.accounts.size() == 1) {
                                    x.accounts.get(0).deposit(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                                            .showInputDialog("Enter how many dollars you want to deposit.\n")));
                                } else {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.accounts.size());
                                    String a = (JOptionPane
                                            .showInputDialog("Enter the account name to deposit into.\n"));
                                    for (Bank act : x.accounts) {
                                        if (act.getAccountName().equalsIgnoreCase(a))
                                            act.deposit(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                                    "Enter how many dollars you want to deposit.\n")));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                if (x.accounts.size() == 0)
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have any accounts!");
                                else if (x.accounts.size() == 1) {
                                    x.accounts.get(0).withdraw(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                                            .showInputDialog("Enter how many dollars you want to withdraw.\n")));
                                } else {
                                    String a = (JOptionPane
                                            .showInputDialog("Enter the account name to withdraw from.\n"));
                                    for (Bank act : x.accounts) {
                                        if (act.getAccountName().equalsIgnoreCase(a))
                                            act.deposit(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                                    "Enter how many dollars you want to withdraw.\n")));
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                x.passwordSet((JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your new password.\n")));
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                x.createNewAccount();
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                logout = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        } while (!logout);
                    } else
                        incun = true;
                }
            }
            if (incun)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or password");
            break;
        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for using the JacoBank");
            exit = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print(Bank.size());
            System.out.print(FF.accounts.size());
            break;

        }
    } while (!exit);
}

public String getAccountHolderName() {
    return accountHolderName;
}

public void setAccountHolderName(String accountHolderName) {
    this.accountHolderName = accountHolderName;
}

public String getAccountUsername() {
    return accountUsername;
}

@Override
public void passwordSet(String password) {
    accountPassword = password;

}
}

class Manage {

}

class Checking extends Bank {
private int checkCount;
}

class Savings extends Bank {
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: If you want help with this project I feel like you should put it on BitBucket, GitHub, GitLab, etc. It will make it easier for someone to run the code in its entirety.

Comment: In the `main` method you only ever create one instance of `FinancialFolk`: `FinancialFolk FF = new FinancialFolk();`. The `FinancialFolk.createNewPerson` method does not create a new person, it merely sets the name and password of the existing instance.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Correct me if I am wrong, but what I did/attempted to do was make FF and then add FF to the arraylist of FinancialFolks as needed.

Comment: Does this sample compile? In your public static void main, I see "Bank.add(FF);", but I do not see an "add" method in the bank class?

Comment: @Solace, Bank is an arraylist and arraylist already have a .add method.

Comment: I think Thomas is right. You only made a single instance of FinancialFolk in your main method. To verify, try looping through your arraylist of FinancialFolk and print each one out. It should print out a memory address and see if they are all the same

Comment: @Solace Yes the same memory address is outputted. This led me to realize I did not put the initialization of FF inside of case 0 so that it reinitialize every time a new account is created. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected static ArrayList<Bank> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

The definition of static in the context of instance variables is that all instances of the class (in this case "FinancialFolk") share the **same copy** of the variable. This is why you are seeing an account added for everyone when you make a new account.

In other words: every "FinancialFolk" object's "accounts" variable is pointing to the exact same arraylist in the heap because of the keyword static.

Comment: I edited my code according to that however the same thing is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

**FinancialFolk FF = new FinancialFolk();**

Above line should be in do-while loop. You have created only one object and making changes to same object for all user accounts.

Comment: Thanks, I realized this as well a minute before you posted it, however thanks so much for the help :)